# Not deleting from array in Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, arrays

This is my first attempt at learning Ruby, and I'm almost there.. this is working except for one piece.. in the function pc_draw the script asks the user if they have a card. If they do then they should be removed from both the "computer's" hand as well as the users hand.. But some reason its not.. Any idea why?

Love to hear some feedback on the code in general as well, any tips or ways to write more concisely or efficiently??

Thanks! and here is the code (edited to just include the relevant code..

```
def pc_draw # this is the PC playing, id dups, if none then draw, if some then delete and draw..
    #first I have to identify the duplicates..
    dup = @pc_cards.detect {|e| @pc_cards.rindex(e) != @pc_cards.index(e) }

    if dup == nil # if no dups exist then PC has to ask for a card..
        @ask_card = rand(@pc_cards.length) # assigns a random number limited to the length of the array
        puts "#{@name} do you have a #{@pc_cards[@ask_card]}? Yes or No? " # ask for a random card in the array.. 
        @user_answer = $stdin.gets.chomp
        pc_gofish(@user_answer, @ask_card)

    else #if there are dups then take them out of the array.
        @pc_cards.delete(dup)
        @ask_card = rand(@pc_cards.length) # assigns a random number limited to the length of the array
        puts "#{@name} do you have a #{@pc_cards[@ask_card]}? Yes or No? " # ask for a random card in the array.. 
        @user_answer = $stdin.gets.chomp
        pc_gofish(@user_answer, @ask_card)
    end

end

def pc_gofish(take, card_delete) #this will deal with the PC asking the user for cards
    if take == "yes" # if the user enters in that their is a match we delete it from pc & user array
        @pc_cards.delete(card_delete)
        @kates_cards.delete(card_delete)
        puts "The computer has #{@pc_cards.length} cards left!" #lets user know how many cards the PC has left

            if @pc_cards.length == 0 # if the array is empty then the pc won!
                puts "The computer won!! Sorry!"
            else @pc_cards.length != 0 # if the array isn't empty, turn reverts back to user.
                draw
            end

    else #this is when there is no match.. so PC has to take a card.. 
        pc_random = rand(@cards.length) # this assigns a random number constrained to the length of the cards remaining
        @pc_cards << pc_random # this inserts that random card into the users ask
        @cards.delete(pc_random) # this takes the card from the deck of cards..
        puts "The computer has #{@pc_cards.length} cards left!" #lets user know how many cards the PC has left
        draw

    end


end
```

Comment: It would really be better if you were able to pin point the issue you are having and only paste that bit of code, instead of pasting your entire application. This is usually called a Minimum Working Example.

Comment: Regarding the code itself, I'll paraphrase  one sentence which changed the way I code: 'everytime you have to put a comment in your code, it is because you fail to write it correctly'

Comment: Another luminary once said, "every time you have to put a comment in your code, it is because there is no other way to make your code clear without mucking it up or wasting the day away."

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me like your detect block is only going to return the first value of the first duplicated item; if you have more than one duplicate, the other duplicates won't be removed.

Eg:

```
a = [1,2,2,3,4,5,5,5,6]
dups = a.detect{|e| a.rindex(e) != a.index(e)} # => returns 2, but not 5
```

I don't know how you've modeled your cards, but you could possibly just uniq the array if you're concerned that duplicates exist:

```
@pc_cards.uniq! # deletes non-uniq elements from the array.
```

Update: I re-read your question, I see you're asking about the computers cards, which I assume are kept in @cards? Ultimately, I need to agree with the comments above: you have too much code here, and you aren't clearly saying *which* part is failing.

I would look into either debugger or pry to inspect your code as it runs, or simply put some `puts` statements into your code so you can see exactly what is really happening at each point.

Answer (score 0):

Try using delete! Instead of delete.